# problem while compiling java code on network drive, it creating class files in lowercase

Tags: java, compiler-construction, clearcase, case-sensitive

i am using clear-case source control, i created my vob repository(which has my java source code) on the network drive, when i rum my javac compiler on the source it compiles fine but it is generating class files in lowercase where it should start with uppercase letter. i have seen the code every thing mentioned perfect. then i tried to create a sample java code on the network drive and i tried to rename it in uppercase but it is automatically changing into lower case. do any one has solution for this?

Comment: What kind of a "network drive"?

Comment: What is this network drive? What file system? What OS? How is it mounted?

Comment: it is  ntfs, windows xp is the os
it is mounted on clearcase server which is on windows nt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are in a dynamic view, check your MVFS settings

- Case insensitive MVFS
- Case Preserving

See this picture.

[image: MVFS settings]

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the Samba SMB server has options for "fixing" the case of file names.  You may want to look into you SMB configuration.